# Average expected number of throws

Tags: probability, statistics

Rene throws the ball into the river, then retrieves it, turns it randomly and throws it again. With each throw, exactly half of the ball gets wet (the lower hemisphere). How many times, on average, does Rene need to throw a ball to get it completely wet (each point of its surface at least once was in the lower hemisphere)?

I found an [article](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath327/kmath327.htm) by Kevin Brown that talks about a simple formula for the probability that $n$ random points on a sphere lie in the same hemisphere. In our case, this formula $p_{n}=\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2^{n}}$ valid for all $n\geq 2$ gives the probability that we will need $n$ throws to completely wet the ball. From this probability, the average number of throws needed to completely wet the sphere is $7$.

I suppose it will also be possible to run a Monte Carlo simulation to verify this. Am I on the right track?

Comment: I think that is correct. I get the same $p_n=P(X=n)$, using $P(X=n)=P(X\ge n)-P(X\ge n-1)$ where $P(X\ge n)=\frac{n^2-n+2}{2^n}$ is taken in the paper. This does give expected value $7$.

Comment: I meant $P(X=n)=P(X>n-1)-P(X>n)$ where $P(X>n)=\frac{n^2-n+2}{2^n}$.